# Kong/Scylladb intermittent timeout issue when writing routes "received only 0 responses 2" - K8

Tags: database, kubernetes, timeout, kong, scylla

When trying to register routes via Kong /routes, we are seeing intermittent timeout issues.

Kong and Scylladb are setup in docker/k8

```
[error] 41#0: *119054033 [kong] api_helpers.lua:310 could not execute insertion query: [Write timeout] Operation timed out for kong.routes - received only 0 responses from 2 CL=SERIAL., client: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: kong_admin, request: \"POST /routes HTTP/1.1\"
```

Only happens on /routes registration call, and write_request_timeout_in_ms is set to 2000ms.

Anyone seen this issue before?